# Struct property accessable from method but not from outside

Tags: rust

I'm trying to build a basic web crawler in Rust, which I'm trying to port to [html5ever](https://github.com/servo/html5ever). As of right now, I have a function with a struct inside that is supposed to return a `Vec<String>`. It gets this `Vec` from the struct in the return statement. Why does it always return an empty vector? (Does it have anything to do with the lifetime parameters?)

```
fn find_urls_in_html<'a>(
    original_url: &Url,
    raw_html: String,
    fetched_cache: &Vec<String>,
) -> Vec<String> {
    #[derive(Clone)]
    struct Sink<'a> {
        original_url: &'a Url,
        returned_vec: Vec<String>,
        fetched_cache: &'a Vec<String>,
    }

    impl<'a> TokenSink for Sink<'a> {
        type Handle = ();

        fn process_token(&mut self, token: Token, _line_number: u64) -> TokenSinkResult<()> {
            trace!("token {:?}", token);
            match token {
                TagToken(tag) => {
                    if tag.kind == StartTag && tag.attrs.len() != 0 {
                        let _attribute_name = get_attribute_for_elem(&tag.name);

                        if _attribute_name == None {
                            return TokenSinkResult::Continue;
                        }
                        let attribute_name = _attribute_name.unwrap();

                        for attribute in &tag.attrs {
                            if &attribute.name.local != attribute_name {
                                continue;
                            }

                            trace!("element {:?} found", tag);
                            add_urls_to_vec(
                                repair_suggested_url(
                                    self.original_url,
                                    (&attribute.name.local, &attribute.value),
                                ),
                                &mut self.returned_vec,
                                &self.fetched_cache,
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
                ParseError(error) => {
                    warn!("error parsing html for {}: {:?}", self.original_url, error);
                }
                _ => {}
            }
            return TokenSinkResult::Continue;
        }
    }

    let html = Sink {
        original_url: original_url,
        returned_vec: Vec::new(),
        fetched_cache: fetched_cache,
    };

    let mut byte_tendril = ByteTendril::new();
    {
        let tendril_push_result = byte_tendril.try_push_bytes(&raw_html.into_bytes());

        if tendril_push_result.is_err() {
            warn!("error pushing bytes to tendril: {:?}", tendril_push_result);
            return Vec::new();
        }
    }

    let mut queue = BufferQueue::new();
    queue.push_back(byte_tendril.try_reinterpret().unwrap());
    let mut tok = Tokenizer::new(html.clone(), std::default::Default::default()); // default default! default?
    let feed = tok.feed(&mut queue);

    return html.returned_vec;
}
```

The output ends with no warning (and a panic, caused by another function due to this being empty). Can anyone help me figure out what's going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A definition of a struct *and* an implementation inside a body of a function? You might want to restructure your code, because this is not very readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I initialize the `Tokenizer`, I use:

```
let mut tok = Tokenizer::new(html.clone(), std::default::Default::default());
```

The problem is that I'm telling the Tokenizer to use `html.clone()` instead of `html`. As such, it is writing `returned_vec` to the cloned object, not `html`. Changing a few things, such as using a variable with mutable references, fixes this problem.